# Finding max of a column while doing inner join of two tables

Tags: sql, hive

I have two tables as follows:

```
Table A
=====================
student_id test_week
 --------   ---------
   s1      2018-12-01
   s1      2018-12-08

Table B
======================
student_id  last_updated remarks
 --------    ------------ --------
   s1        2018-12-06   Fail
   s1        2018-12-10   Pass
```

Above two tables, I want to fetch following columns:

student_id, last(test_week) and remarks such that

```
last_updated>=test_week -1 and last_updated<=test_week-15,
```

i.e. last_updated should be within two weeks of last(test_week), so following will be the result for above entries:

```
s1 2018-12-08 Pass
```

I have written like following:

```
 select a.student_id, test_week, remarks
 from A inner join B
 on A.student_id = B.student_id
 and DATEDIFF(last_updated, test_week)>=1
 and DATEDIFF(last_updated, test_week)<=15;
```

But how I will handle the last(test_week), that I am not getting.

Comment: Are you using MySQL version 8? or a variant of MySQL such as MariaDB?

Comment: @Used_By_Already  actually I am executing the above query in Hive, I thought queries in MySQL and Hive are somewhat similar, so tagged them. I would correct the tag.

Comment: @Joy . . . I don't get the purpose of the 2 week period.  Why not just take the last result in the second table?

Answer (score 0):

If you need the only record related to the last test_week then you can do the following. If I understood this right.

```
 select top 1 a.student_id, test_week, remarks
 from A inner join B
 on A.student_id = B.student_id
 and DATEDIFF(last_updated, test_week)>=1
 and DATEDIFF(last_updated, test_week)<=15 
 order by last_week desc;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use window function `row_number()`. The following query will give the max(test_week) for every student_id.

```
select * from (
       select id, test_week, remarks, row_number()
       over (partition by id order by test_week desc) as rn 
       from (
            select a.id, test_week, remarks from A join B on A.id = B.id and last_updated - test_week >=1 and last_updated - test_week <=15)tb1
            )tb2 where rn=1;
```

Note : The above query is supported in postgresql, you might want to convert it into equivalent Mysql query